# UWP graph-tutorial AadLogin button not showing

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, azure-active-directory

Using the Microsoft Graph Quick Start tutorial, I did all of the steps (register app, got app id, went to the azure portal, added redirect, downloaded the zip, extracted). I loaded the solution and built it (using x64). When I run it there is no "sign-in" (AadLogin) button.

I then went through the step by step guide building the application from scratch and I have the same issue at the end of Step 1. All of the code copied correctly, it builds and executes ... but NO still "sign in" button control.

I am building using VS2017 Community Version 15.9.17 and Win10 Enterprise 1709 Build 16299.1451.

MainPage.xaml shows the AadLogin control being added to the page

```
<Grid>
    <NavigationView x:Name="NavView"
        IsSettingsVisible="False"
        ItemInvoked="NavView_ItemInvoked">

        <NavigationView.Header>
            <graphControls:AadLogin x:Name="Login"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                View="SmallProfilePhotoLeft"
                AllowSignInAsDifferentUser="False"
                />
        </NavigationView.Header>
```

The video from the step-by-step instructions shows the control and it working but I am getting nothing.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I download the sample code from https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-uwp and just rename the OAuth.resw.example file to OAuth.resw without any other operations. Then I click on F5, the "sign-in" (AadLogin) button is shown correctly. Can you see the button in designer?

Comment: Have you tried the sample code from the link I shared? Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: @AllenWu I cannot see the designer at all. I get a message saying I need a newer version of Windows (version 1809) to display the content. I can see the control in the XAML code.

I followed your instructions and downloaded, unzipped Demo 3, renamed the file (without ".example") and the control **still** does not show up.

Answer (score 0):

Please download the sample code from [Microsoft Graph Training Module - Build UWP apps with the Microsoft Graph .NET SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-uwp) and configure the third project: 03-add-msgraph by following [How to run the completed project](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-uwp/tree/master/Demos/03-add-msgraph).

To just show the button, it's unnecessary to finish all the configuration. Just rename the OAuth.resw.example file to OAuth.resw and run the project.